# Wordpress ajax theme. Ajax does not work. No new data in table in db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I cant understand why my code does not work.
I have a tabel wp_subscibe with id, user_id and post_id. I want after click on button to add this data to my db by ajax. Please, look at my code. 
This is my html in single.php:

```
<button type="submit" name="subscribe" id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
 <input id="postId" type="hidden" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
```

My subscribe.js:

```
onSubscribe: function() {
        var $onSubscr = $('#subscribe');

        $onSubscr.on('click', function() {
            var $el = $(this),
                post_id = $('#postId').val(),
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: admin_url.ajaxurl,
                dataType:"json",
                //data : 'action=subscribeOn&post_id='+post_id
                data: {
                    action: 'subscribeOn',
                    post_id: post_id
                },
                cache: false
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

And functions.php:

```
wp_register_script( 'subscribe', THEME_DIR . '/js/subscribe.js', array(), '', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'subscribe' );
wp_localize_script( 'subscribe',  'admin_url', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));


function subscribeOn() {
global $wpdb, $user_id, $post_id;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

//    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "subscribe";
$wpdb->insert("wp_subscribe", array(  'user_id'=>$user_id, 'post_id'=>$post_id), array('%s','%s'));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribeOn', 'subscribeOn' );
add_action('wp_ajax_subscribeOn', 'subscribeOn)');
```

Can anybody tell me where is my problem? Nothing happens in wp_subscribe in db. I try so many ways, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console window?

Comment: in network after click on button i have my POST and admin-ajax.php, which has Form data: action=subscribeOn&post_id=23. Looks like Ok. About request / response in the browser's console window I dont know how to write that properly to be honest

Comment: add_action('wp_ajax_subscribeOn', 'subscribeOn)'); <--syntax error

Answer (score 0):

For debug of javascript you need to get used to using the console (for chrome, right click on the page and "inspect element" you will see console on the top of the pop up. This will list any errors or outputs from js.

A common mistake with jQuery and wordpress is to use `$` without defining it, so you need `$='jQuery';` before you can use the $ operator to refer to jQuery or substitute the use of $ for the word jQuery. Look up no conflict jQuery for more information.

Another common error in wp ajax and localize script is ajaxurl. For the moment enter in the static value which is `www.yourserver.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` in most set ups, the wp-admin folder could be somewhere else on your server of course. You should test using `console.log(admin_url.ajaxurl);` the output will appear in the console mentioned earlier.

Updated code (dont wrap in a function and assign to a variable, just use it as is.

```
$=jQuery;
$(document).on('click', '#subscribe', function() {
            var post_id = $('#postId').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // common error is ajax.url undefined (insert your home url into the start of the string, we will eliminate any possibility of mistake by using a static url. 
                //dataType:"json",
                //data : 'action=subscribeOn&post_id='+post_id
                data: {
                    action: 'subscribeOn',
                    post_id: post_id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data); //this writes any output from the server into the console, so if theres a respose you know ajaxurl and jquery is more or less correct, so its good to return something whilst testing... 
                },  
                cache: false
            });

  });
```

now for the server. When testing you should return something (any data you output using `echo` `var_dump` etc will be returned and as we added a command in our browser code to output this to the console we can check for it there.

```
function subscribeOn() {
    global $wpdb, $user_id, $post_id;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    // we insert this to test the jQuery settings are correct. if one of the below does not appear in the console, we have issues in jQuery. 
    if($post_id):
        echo $post_id;
    else:
        echo 'no post id is being submitted check selectors';
    endif;  

    $success= $wpdb->insert("wp_subscribe", 
        array(  'user_id'=>$user_id, 'post_id'=>$post_id), 
        array('%s','%s') 
    );

    if($success):
        echo 'successfully inserted';
    else:
        echo 'not inserted, is the table name correct, etc? does the function work elsewhere?'; 
    endif;

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribeOn', 'subscribeOn' );  
add_action('wp_ajax_subscribeOn', 'subscribeOn)');
```

hopefully this will sort it. If it does hit the correct icon beside this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way myself. it was just because one bracket after subscribeOn!

```
add_action('wp_ajax_subscribeOn', 'subscribeOn)');
```